# when click certain td open the whole table in new window

Tags: php, html

3 hours till now and i am tring to figure this out but now luck.

i have a page it content consist of several html table each one has certain td

where it look like this

`<td style="padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;" valign="middle"><span class="lshevent">team a  - team b </span></td>`

i want to make this td as hyperlink when someone click this Td open the whole table in new window .

my page source is retreived from remote page through file get contents as below

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://remotesite/pages/page1.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

    $toRemove = array();

    // gather a list of tbodys to remove
    foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'desktop') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;    

            foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'Recommended') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;  

    // remove them
    foreach($toRemove as $tbody)
      $tbody->parentNode->removeChild($tbody);

    echo str_replace('</h3><table','<table',$doc->saveHTML());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting a `onclick="openInNewWindow();"` and in that function call ajax with your code, well also a possibility would be to just put an ID on  and `$('#<your_id>').click(function(){});` and when ajax will return success the `window.open();`

sorry, well, roughly it will look like this:

`html -> <td id="open">` or `<td onclick="openWindow();">`

`js:`

```
$(function(){
   $('#open').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type : 'POST',
         data: {},
         dataType : 'html',
         url : '/remotesite/getSite', //here goes the link to your php function(if you are using MVC logic then it will look like this)
         success: function(data){
             myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
             myWindow.document.write(data);
         }  
      });
   });
});
```

or

```
function openWindow(){
   //copy the $.ajax function from above here
}
```

and in php just create a controller (that depends if you have MVC logic on your webpage if not then the actual path to the file you are using)

```
public function getSite(){
   //your code here and echo the template or html code where 
   //where you have your table like echo $html_code;
}
```

EDITED:
Sorry that i didn't post the code before